# Updated Discord Bot Problem WIth Node.js and Command Prompt

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

When I would enter

"node index.js"

Into Command Prompt & the folder with all of the Discord bot information, it'd give me this error:

```
const client = Discord.Client();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token const
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Anyway to fix?

Edit:

config.json

```
{ 
"BOT_TOKEN": "bot's token"
}
```

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('bot's token');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json')

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

I corrected your index.js code.

**The Problems could be the following :**

1. You might haven't install Discord.js or you are using an outdated version of Node.js use `npm i -g npm` and `npm i discord.js` to add discord.js.
2. Your token is invalid? try updating your token and put the new token there.

If you did all this, and hadn't work yet then i have no idea.
From what i know, it should've work

I can't do anything about it because you didn't provide much info.
But let me know if it does work or if you have additional information.